# VBS(Virtualization Based Security) on Linux, Kernel protection using hardware based virtualization. Is it planned to be embedded in a distro?

Tags: kernel, security, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

https://www.linux-kvm.org/images/4/40/01x05-Jun_Nakajima-Kernel_Protection_Using_Hardware-Based_Virtualization.pdf

We have already VBS(Virtualization Based Security) in Windows 11. I do need that technology in Ubuntu. When do we have it in Ubuntu distro?

Answer (score 0):

You can run it using `wine` on Ubuntu.

For installing `wine`:

1. Open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> or Applications Overview → Terminal.
2. Install Wine from the official repositories or [from `wine`'s official repositories](https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/). For installing from Ubuntu's official repositories, run:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install wine -y
   ```

After `wine` is installed, you can  run the `.vbs` files using `wine`:

```
wine cscript script.vbs
```

You can also use:

```
wine wscript script.vbs
```

Comment: VBS(Virtualization Based Security)